# Написание шаблонизатора с собственным синтаксисом

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы

Хочу попробовать написать шаблонизатор с собственным синтаксисом (для начала чтобы, к примеру, вывод переменной выглядел так: `{{var}}`). Вопрос: как реализовать такой функционал?

Comment: @sargss Ух ты, гляньте сперва [мой вопрос заданный здесь](http://goo.gl/6isQkE) в далёком 2012 и, собственно, [результат работы](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-template). А теперь, задайтесь вопросом, Вы уверены в своих силах?

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match_all()|preg_replace()` - остов всего.

Comment: @TheDoctor, любой более-менее серьезный анализатор сначала должен побить шаблон на лексемы и соорудить дерево, тут на одних регулярках не выехать.

Comment: @Etki, это понятно, но человек явно только начал копать, разбивать на лексемы, думаю, рано, сначала пусть поиграет.
P. S. Сам я понятия не имею как они работают, если честно, всё никак руки не доходят препарировать их.

Comment: @TheDoctor Хорошо известные нам шаблонизаторы [используют токенизацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/tokens.php), переводя их облегчённый синтаксис в нативный php. Естественно, всё это дело кэшируется в php-файлы. 

> побить шаблон на лексемы и соорудить дерево

@Etki прав.

Comment: @romeo, это я знаю, другой вопрос - как?  
По большим проектам типа Smarty сложно учится, когда я препарировал XenForo, эта истина дошла до меня хорошо.  Зато многое почерпнул :)

Comment: @TheDoctor *как будто я знаю*. В общем случае - посимвольный проход с анализом предшествующей и последующей части на соответствие управляющим конструкциям, но вообще, я так понимаю, универсальным ответом на этот вопрос является dragon book.

Comment: @TheDoctor вот и я надеюсь что-то почерпнуть. Статей на эту тему я не нашел(возможно плохо искал)

Comment: @Etki, Это был риторический вопрос (хотя ссылочку на хорошую статью я всегда рад увидеть) :)  
Книга дракона - это что?
@sargss, лучший учитель - практика. Разбирай уже созданные движки и, конечно, задавай тут такие вопросы, желательно более точные.

Comment: @TheDoctor http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools

я ее не открывал пока, но в планах.

Comment: @Etki, благодарю.  
Пробовал написать компилятор, почитал пару статей на хабре и как-то быстро перехотел, в вебе поспокойней будет.

Comment: YACC и Lex - наше фсе! :) В далеком 1991-м за неделю на них сварганил что-то наподобие джавовского компайлера плюс интерпретатор для выполнения получившегося при компиляции байт-кода. Все это использовалось в банковской проге для расчетов сложных процентов по вкладам